# FSL error inv(): matrix appears to be singular

Tags: matrix

I am conducting analysis of imaging data, performing fiber tracking using FSL probtrackx2. However, I encounter the following error message:

error: inv(): matrix appears to be singular

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: inv(): matrix appears to be singular
Abort trap: 6

Because this does not seem to be necessarily related to FSL specifically, could anyone explain what this mean? 
Not sure if the information I provided is enough, I can explain in more detail if necessary

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.
The reason for that is the ROI head information and the Image head information not matched, especially the Qform.

Thank you [Saad](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A2=ind1906&L=FSL&P=R21553&X=8B884DAEEA12BB3C86&Y=yeningrong0%40163.com) point out the error!

It can be fixed by the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ROI=$1
target=$2 # raw image/ standard image/T1 image, depend on where roi came from.
result_path=$3
# this script is for probtrackx2_gpu, for every roi feed into probtrack2 should have the same qform/sform as raw image or standard image.
mkdir -p $result_path
ROI_name0=`basename $ROI`
ROI_name=${ROI_name0%.nii.gz}
target_name0=`basename $target`
target_name=${target_name0%.nii.gz}
ROI_checked=$result_path/${ROI_name}_hdchecked.nii.gz
cp $ROI $ROI_checked
fslhd_ROI=$result_path/${ROI_name}.fslhd.txt
fslhd_target=$result_path/${target_name}.fslhd.txt
if [ -f $fslhd_target ]; then
        echo $target_name fslhd file exist!
else
        fslhd $target>$fslhd_target
        echo $target_name fslhd file generated.
fi
if [ -f $fslhd_ROI ]; then
        echo $ROI_name fslhd file exist!
else
        fslhd $ROI>$fslhd_ROI
        echo $ROI_name fslhd file generated.
fi
diff $fslhd_target $fslhd_ROI > $result_path/${ROI_name}_${target_name}.diff.txt
ROI_target_diff=`grep -Fxvf $fslhd_target $fslhd_ROI`
if [[ $ROI_target_diff == *"qform"* ]] || [[ $ROI_target_diff == *"sform"* ]] ; then
        echo $ROI and $target are different in qform or sform!
        fslcpgeom $target $ROI_checked -d
        echo copy geom information qform/sform from $target .
fi
echo please use $ROI_checked in probtrackx2.
```